# Dynamically Pass Parent POM version

Tags: maven, pom.xml, parent-pom

I am trying to dynamically pass the parent pom version in my pom as shown below.

```
<parent>
        <groupId>com.maventest</groupId>
        <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
        <version>${env.myversion}</version>
</parent>
```

I have tried with both environment variable as shown above and also tried with passing variable with -D and then access as `${myversion}`. None is working for me.

Can someone kindly help.

Comment: Can you explain why you need to change the parent version dynamically ?

Answer (score 0):

This does not work because maven resolves the dependencies in the first step before resolving the variables.

Starting with Maven 3.5.0-beta-1 you can use the `${revision}`, `${sha1}` and/or `${changelist}` as placeholders for the version in your pom file. These are three special properties that will be resolved earlier.

You can look for "Maven CI Friendly Versions" for further information: https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html

Comment: That helps. I did not realize that things changed with the version.

Comment: That does not work for the parent...

Comment: In a setup where the parent POM is in a remote repository, the reference to the parent's version in the child POM must be to a specific, resolvable version without using CI-friendly variables from the child POM.